# While nested in Foreach triggers - Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object

Tags: php

I keep getting a "Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object" error on a script I know is array.  Basic code is:

Array is built from an API call -

```
$results = $abc->request('thing', $params, 'GET');
```

I've confirmed via `print_r` that `$results` is in fact an array - here is a sample

```
 Array
    (
         [currentPage] => 1
         [numberOfPages] => 196
         [totalResults] => 9754
         [data] => Array
             (
               [0] => Array
                 (
                   [id] => 1234
                   [name] => Robert
                   [nameShortDisplay] => Bob
                   [description] => Lorem....
                  )
              )

         [status] => success
  )
```

My code that is an issue is supposed to loop through the array and while looping clean up the data and insert into my DB

```
foreach ($results as $each_results) { 
    while (list($key, $value) = each ($each_results)) { 
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $results[data][$key][id]); ...
```

Why is saying that Variable passed to each() is not an array?

Comment: `var_dump($each_results)`…?

Comment: Perform `var_dump($each_results);` and find out. My guess is your first var_dump will contain a string of `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach ($results as $each_results) {` is going to iterate all of the values in the `$results` array (1, 196, 9754, etc.).

Some of the values aren't arrays, which is why you get that error. But based on what you're doing in the while loop, it looks like you should be able to just iterate the `data` key directly.

```
foreach ($results['data'] as $entry) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $entry['id']);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Don't Panic!!  Not only did you help me understand the issue you have me a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` statement takes the array in `$results` and iterates over it, assigning each element of the array to `$each_results`.